# Как в editText при вводе, убрать 0(если только он), и заменить тем что вводится?

Tags: android, android-edittext, edittext

У меня проблема, я в editText не могу оставить пустое поле, могу позволить пользователю удалить все, но я должен подставить 0, ниже код как я это делаю. Мне нужно чтобы когда клиент начнет вводить свое значение, то если в editText стоит только 0, то удалить его при вводе значений пользователем, как будто этот 0 в hint, а не в самом editText. По итогу в логике должно быть так, что если все стираем, ставится 0, начинаем что то вводить, 0 удаляется.

Надеюсь я понятно объяснил. Просто я уже перепробовал кучу всего, и у меня не получается добиться такой логики.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
// Проверяем все ли удалили в минимальной цене, в фильтрах
if(s.length() == 0){
   catalog_filter_price_max.setText("0");
   catalog_filter_price_min.setSelection(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: По моему, проблема именно в этом: "я в editText не могу оставить пустое поле". Это почему так?

Comment: Не проще ли проверять перед использованием этого значения в коде? Если пусто - то писать 0.

Comment: @DrMcSheen у нас в приложении есть проверка на пустое поле, и оно не может быть пустым, потому что из него берется значение, которое участвует в запросе для фильтра, если поле оставить пустым, приложение зависает. Нужно просто при начале набора значений в editText как то проверять, если ли там 0, и удалять его просто. Такая реализация должна существовать, но у меня не получается сделать так.

Comment: "из него берется значение, которое участвует в запросе для фильтра" –  Так вот тут и делай проверку и дописывай 0, если там пусто

Answer (score 0):

Сделать проверку того что введено можно после завершения ввода через этот метод:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  
}
```

добавляем в тело проверку на размер того что "осталось" после редактирования текста:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   if(s.length() == 0){
   catalog_filter_price_max.setText("0");
   catalog_filter_price_min.setSelection(0);
   }
}
```